# Pass Id value to a modal form in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, modal-dialog

i have a list of users and i want to change permission for each user for that matter i have a button on each user row so when i click on it a modal form pops up with a select input and a submit button as follow :

1- this is the button

```
<a  value ="<?= $value['id'];?>" class=" btn btn-secondary btn-sm  btn-info permission" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-center" title="Permission">
                                <i class="fas fa-user "></i>
                            </a>
```

2- this is the modal form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-center" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Center modal</h5>
        </div>
        <form class="mt-4" action="<?php echo base_url('User/add_mem_to_group/'.$value['id']); ?>" method="post">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="Permission">
            <option selected value="1">Admin</option>
            <option value="2">Moderator</option>
            <option value="3">Client</option>
            
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

3- i have a controller which contains the function add_mem_to_group which is responsible for getting the id and input result to grant the user the permission.

im stuck how to pass the Id to the modal form

Comment: Is there something to stop you from using a hidden HTML input type, something like this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Comment: User/add_mem_to_group/'.$value['id'] as you can see here i want to get the id of the relevant row however in this case the $value['id'] will be the last value loaded so in case i have 6 rows id will be always =6  and i will update number 6

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.view_data').click(function(){  
       var id = $(this).attr("id");  
       console.log(id);
  });  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <button class="btn btn-primary view_data" id="1" >VIEW INFO</button>
```

**View Code:-**

```
<tr>
   <td>
  <button class="btn btn-primary view_data" id="<?php echo $e->id; ?>" ><i class="icon-eye-open">VIEW INFO</i></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Bootstrap Modal Code:-**

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">VIEW FULL INFO</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="your_modal_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

**JQUERY AJAX Code:-**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.view_data').click(function(){  
       var id = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url : "<?php echo base_url('ControllerName/get_Full_data') ?>", 
            type:"POST",  
            data:{id:id},  
            success:function(data){
            //alert(data);  
             $('#your_modal_detail').html(data);  
             $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });  
</script>
```